# How do I make 69! comparisons in a 2D array of size array[69][51]

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

The array holds student responses to a survey, and I'm trying to find out which students had the most answers in common. The 2D array has 69 rows for the 69 responses, and the survey was 50 questions long plus one index for their name.

```
public static void mostMatches(String[][] results){

      int mostMatches=0;
      int mostMatchIndex=0;

      int mostMatchIndex2=0;

      int tempIndex=0;
      int matches=0;

      for (int k=0; k<results.length;k++){
          for(int i=1;i<results.length;i++){    
              matches=0;
                  for(int j=1;j<results[0].length;j++){
                        if (results[i][j].equals(results[k][j])){
                            matches++;
                            tempIndex=i;
                        }
                }  
            if (matches>=mostMatches ){
                mostMatches = matches;
                mostMatchIndex2 = mostMatchIndex;
                mostMatchIndex = tempIndex;
                }

        }
      }//end of k iteration

    System.out.print("Most matches with "+results[mostMatchIndex][0]+" was "+results[mostMatchIndex2][0]+" with "+mostMatches+" matches" );
} //end of MostMaches
```

The results of this code just tell me the last two data entries are the highest match with 50/50 matches (there is no one with 50/50 matches). Can someone point me in the right direction with my logical errors?

Answer (score 0):

the loop should be like

```
 for (int k=0; k<results.length-1;k++)
      for(int i=k+1;i<results.length;i++)
```

you get 50/50 just because i=k.